# Print input / output / grad / loss at every step/epoch when training Transformers HuggingFace model

Tags: python, logging, neural-network, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm working on HuggingFace Transformers and using toy example from here:
https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html#fine-tuning-with-trainer

What I actually need: ability to print input, output, grad and loss at every step.
It is trivial using Pytorch training loop, but it is not obvious using HuggingFace `Trainer`.
At the current moment I have next idea: create a `CustomCallback` like this:

```
class MyCallback(TrainerCallback):
    "A callback that prints a grad at every step"

    def on_step_begin(self, args, state, control, **kwargs):
        print("next step")
        print(kwargs['model'].classifier.out_proj.weight.grad.norm())

args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='test_dir',
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=1,
    logging_steps=100,
    report_to="none",
    fp16=True,
    disable_tqdm=True,
)


trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=test_dataset,
    callbacks=[MyCallback],
)

trainer.train()
```

This way I can print grad and weights for any model layer.
But I still can't figure out how to print input/output (for example, I want to check them on `nan`) and loss?

P.S. I also read something about `forward_hook` but still can't find good code examples for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using hooks and custom callbacks is the right way to solve the problem I find better solution - use built-in utility for finding `nan/Inf` in losses / weights / inputs / outputs:
https://huggingface.co/transformers/internal/trainer_utils.html#transformers.debug_utils.DebugUnderflowOverflow
since the 4.6.0 transformers has such option.

You can use it manually in `forward` function or just use additional option for `TrainingArguments` like this:

```
args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='test_dir',
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=1,
    logging_steps=100,
    report_to="none",
    fp16=True,
    disable_tqdm=True,
    debug="debug underflow_overflow"
)
```